# Wordpress REST API - Image not showing up

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cors, wordpress-rest-api

I want to display a **IMG** through the **Wordpress REST API**. I got the image url successfully, however it won't display.
I assumed it was due to **CORS headers**, but that does not seem to be the case.

I got my file saved on:
http://localhost:63342/testsite/index.html

```
<img src="{{ image.url }}" />
//compiled through handlebars.js ends up like this on the page:
<img src="http://restapi.local/wp-content/uploads/.../image.jpg" />
```

The **response header** looks like this, so there doesn't seem to be a **CORS error**, if i'm not mistaken:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:63342
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
```

adding the **URL directly**, didn't solve the issue.

Comment: how do you retrieve `image.url`? it seems wrong or did you leave out the subfolders with `...` on purpose. Think the url is wrong.

Comment: @niklas `image.url` is simply a placeholder. I was actually able to get the image url when opening the file, after handlebars.js "compiled" it. But as said, it simply won't display. And it's not a CSS fault, I checked that.

Comment: well, this: `http://restapi.local/wp-content/uploads/.../image.jpg` is wrong

Comment: @niklas that's only an example url.